# Bulk Insert with .txt with or without PK Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to insert a .txt files data into my sql-server db. I tried it with and without the PK-Variable in the .txt file both gives me an error. 
My query:

> BULK INSERT DB.Schema.Table    FROM 'C:\Users\test.txt' WITH
>   (FIELDTERMINATOR = ';') GO

1. Without the PK Var i get the error:

> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character
>   for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 1 (PK_ID). Msg 4864,
>   Level 16, State 1, Line 1

1. With the PK Var i get the error:

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Bulk load data conversion error
>   (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for
>   row 1, column 1 (PK_ID). Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1 Violation
>   of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Table'. Cannot insert duplicate key in
>   object 'dbo.Table'. The duplicate key value is (1). The statement has
>   been terminated.

An example of the .txt file content:

PK_ID; VName;NName;UserName;Sex
1;Smith;Smither;SM;male
2;Tim;Timmer;TI;male

AutoIncrem is on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution: I couldnt solve the problem above. Some ppl said to put the ID as columnname into the txt file and leave the entries open (as (,Hans,Maier)), didnt worked for me. I found out that the proper way is to create a staging table. A staging table is just a normal table without the primary key where you bulk insert the data. Here you can manipulate the data as you want. After that you insert the data from that staging table to the table you want. [Insert Data from one table to another](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/15/sql-server-insert-data-from-one-table-to-another-table-insert-into-select-select-into-table/) gives a good description how to do it. The good thing is also that you can update your table since bulk insert just gives you the option to insert data not to update.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your example .txt. file content, I think you are loading the headers as a row into the table.  Try:

```
BULK INSERT DB.Schema.Table FROM 'C:\Users\test.txt' WITH
    (FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
     FIRSTROW=2)
GO
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment. I tried it but still the same Error in both cases (with/without PK)